# Why does my wedding turn into a brawl?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Playing Skyrim, trying to get married to Borgahk the Steel Heart and, upon waiting for the wedding to happen in the Temple of Mara the guests start fighting. I've determined that it might be something to do with Mjoll the Lioness, due to her being the only hostile character on my compass. Everyone in the temple will attack her until she is downed then resume attacking when she stands back up. Is there some way to fix this?

Edit: Not Mjoll, thought it was but it's actually a Bandit Chief with very similar model and the same face-paint. Killing the bandit does end the cycle of fighting and waiting but I am continually told to leave the temple, and find myself unable to.

Comment: Your in-laws sound awful already.

Comment: Why is there a bandit chief in the temple?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie He or She is not there previous to my going in for the wedding. It's almost as if the game think's I need a bandit chief as a guest.

Comment: I think they tell you to get out because they think you started the brawl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after trying on the same try about seven times, then getting derailed while my family took over the TV to watch a hockey game, I tried to do a Cold Feet retry and it worked. Now happily married.

Comment: We've all been there

Answer (score 2):

You need to talk to your new spouse for a remarry and then talk to the priest for the remarry, but only once! Then the wedding will start.